# Estimate resource consumption of an application

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi

I have a query.
I have an X application in my WS 2012, which I have to scale the consumption of RAM and CPU that it will have. Currently when the application works at maximum, the CPU and RAM reach 100%, so I can not estimate how much more RAM and CPU you need and I can not add more resources at the moment to go testing. Is there any way to estimate this consumption, or any tool that does that work? What dou you recommend? Thank you so much!

Comment: There are *a lot* of applications, that do use 100% of cpu/ram, regardless of what you throw at them. also, 100% of a 3640 is not the same as 100% of a gold 6k. so, no ther eis no way to see taht from the outside and without testing.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two approaches:

- Check the application's documentation. The *minimum* and *recommended* system requirements should be noted.
- Test on a beefy system. Take note of how much resources are utilized.